# How to create PDF file with all your bookmarks displayed?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, bookmarks, books

I have a PDF file created with WinEdt 9 (see picture 1). The tex source file is made with class book, obviously generator bookmarks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter [One}
\section{Section two}
\subsection{Section one}
\subsection{Section two}
\section{Section three}
\subsection{Section one}
\subsection{Section two}
\section{Section four}
\subsection{Section one}
\subsection{Section two}
\subsection{Section three}
\end{document}
```

Whenever compiled using PDFLaTeX always have to deploy each of the bookmarks labeled (+). And that is annoying when there are many subgroups (so to speak) of bookmarks with (+).

Specifically:
I want to know if there is any code that you can add to the preamble of my tex file so that the resulting PDF output by default as in picture 2, with bookmarks (+) fully deployed (-).

[image]

I hope let me understand.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example demonstrating the issue. It should begin `\documentclass` and end `\end{document}`.

Comment: @cfr Ok I will do it.

Comment: Try `bookmarksopen=true`. My viewer ignores it, along with the `bookmarks` default for showing them at all. But presumably `acroread` should respect it. (I would test but `acroread` takes half a year to even think about possibly considering opening something, so I figure it will be quicker for you if you're already using it.)

Comment: `\usepackage[open]{bookmark}`

Comment: @cfr Thanks. My tex file compiles perfectly. All bookmarks are open. :)

Comment: @mathsalomon Great. Thanks for confirming. `acroread` is insanely slow on Linux so I avoid using it whenever I have any kind of practical alternative.

Comment: @egreg Thnaks. Also it works.

Comment: @cfr One last question: Is there a possibility that the default PDF is displayed in page width mode?

Comment: Try `pdfstartview=FitH`. There's a list of possible values on page 11 of the manual. `FitH` looks most likely, but there are others if that's not quite right.

Comment: @cfr Yes. It works. Just put ``\usepackage [pdfstartview=FitH]{hyperref}`` Many Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply add `bookmarksopen=true` for the default bookmarks-open to also expand them. I will refrain from posting a screenshot as my viewer ignores all these options anyway and `acroread` simply takes forever to even consider possibly thinking about sometime in the distant future opening a file. (But the OP confirmed that it works in Adobe's viewer.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=black,bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter [One}
\section{Section two}
\subsection{Section one}
\subsection{Section two}
\section{Section three}
\subsection{Section one}
\subsection{Section two}
\section{Section four}
\subsection{Section one}
\subsection{Section two}
\subsection{Section three}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And to open first X levels only use `bookmarksopenlevel=X`.

Answer (score 25):

According to the documentation of `bookmark` you can use the `open` option; if you want to set the level, you can say `openlevel=<level>`; so

```
\usepackage[open,openlevel=1]{bookmark}
```

will show something like

[image]

whereas the simple `open` option will show

[image]

Tested with Skim and Adobe Reader on Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks This is most useful. But he had already voted by the method of user cfr. Thank you anyway.