# How do I create bookmarks with pdfLaTeX?

Tags: bookmarks

I'm using MiKTeX and using pdfLaTeX. I can generate the PDF, but there are no bookmarks. In the `.tex`-file it is using:

```
\chapter
\section
\subsection
```

(with labels)

I originally used make with `sphinx` to output LaTeX. It must work somewhat or I wouldn't get the PDF. When I say bookmarks, I mean when you are in Acrobat and the left side has the Bookmarks panel.

I am reading [How to create PDF file with all your bookmarks displayed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288266/how-to-create-pdf-file-with-all-your-bookmarks-displayed)

But I am not sure where to apply this.

**EDIT:**  I applied this, `\usepackage{bookmark}`, and got bookmarks, but I never get the subsection bookmarks.

Comment: `\usepackage{hyperref}`

Comment: `\usepackage{bookmark}` will also be helpful...

Comment: The depth of the bookmarks can be changed. Read the documentation of bookmark

Comment: `\usepackage[depth=subsection]{bookmark}` will show the subsection bookmarks, the `bookmark` package 'translates' the relevant section level into the level number (which is 2 for subsection, so `depth=2` would work too)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, bookmarks *replicate* the table of contents. So if your ToC shows content up to `\section`, so will the bookmarks. The default *level* up to which content is shown in the ToC is 2 - equivalent to `\subsection` (in `book` and `report`). So, the following minimal example

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents                % Level 0 (chapter)

\chapter{A chapter}             % Level 0
\section{A section}             % Level 1
\subsection{A subsection}       % Level 2
\subsubsection{A subsubsection} % Level 3
\paragraph{A paragraph}         % Level 4
\subparagraph{A subparagraph}   % Level 5

\end{document}
```

shows the bookmarks up to level 2:

[image: ToC/bookmarks up to level 2]

If yours doesn't show up to this level, then you must be using a different class, or perhaps a package that sets a different level of inclusion. This can be changed though...

By adding

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}% Show ToC content up to level 3 (\subsubsection)
```

to your preamble to ToC/bookmarks resemble

[image: ToC/bookmarks up to level 3]

The above works the same with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) as it does with [`bookmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark).

---

You can have different depths of visibility in the ToC and bookmarks. This is provided by the `bookmarks` option `depth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[depth=4]{bookmark}% Show up to level 4 (\paragraph) in bookmarks

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}% Show up to level 3 (\subsubsection) in ToC

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents                % Level 0 (chapter)

\chapter{A chapter}             % Level 0
\section{A section}             % Level 1
\subsection{A subsection}       % Level 2
\subsubsection{A subsubsection} % Level 3
\paragraph{A paragraph}         % Level 4
\subparagraph{A subparagraph}   % Level 5

\end{document}
```