# Show bookmarks in pdf from custom documentclass

Tags: pdftex, bookmarks, documentclass

I have been trying to get the pdf with bookmarks, just like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288266/how-to-create-pdf-file-with-all-your-bookmarks-displayed), but from a custom documentclass from [GitHub](https://github.com/lchamon/poliTeX).
I tried everything from the forums and nothing works from me. The only option in to add manually the pdfbookmark but i want to generate automatically from the ToC.
I am using Texmaker and PDFLatex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Have you tried loading the `bookmark` package?

Comment: Yes, i tried bookmark and hyperref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is faulty. It tries to define its own command for the table of contents, but the definition is faulty.

```
\documentclass{politex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\ABNTaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{abc}
\section{blub}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It has solved my issue.