# Why doesn't my nomenclature get printed out?

Tags: symbols, nomenclature, mathematics

I am facing trouble to print the nomenclature of my thesis because it simply doesn't get printed out.
I'm using more symbols but with those two it's already not working, I am following this tutorial:

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Nomenclatures

The biggest difference is that I am trying to print my nomenclatures before my main text, but I don't think that should really matter, once I must specify the symbols using \nomenclature command. Any ideas on why is it not working?

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
\documentclass[]{politex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\makeglossaries
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
....
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{$\theta$}{Resolução angular de um telescópio}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck constant}

\printnomenclature
....
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is the `politex` class? If I use `article`, it works fine. Did you run MakeIndex?

Comment: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510042/show-bookmarks-in-pdf-from-custom-documentclass). Maybe politex is the problem.

Comment: politex is a customn class used by my unisersity to format its thesis, actually it's a very ill written piece of code, but it's mandatory. I did not run makeindex, where should I put it?

Comment: "badly written, yet mandatory code". that's a summary of so many things.