# Create a Table of Contents for the PDF viewer (not within text)

Tags: table-of-contents

When I use `\tableofcontents` it generates the toc within the PDF itself. I wonder how a toc can be generated for the PDF viewer, say with Preview on a Mac.

Comment: if you mean bookmarks: load either hyperref or the bookmark package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that worked, tks++

Answer (score 1):

With `\usepackage{bookmark}` you can achieve this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1}

        \subsection{Subsection 1}
        
            \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
    
    \section{Section 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more I suggest you check out: [How to create PDF file with all your bookmarks displayed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288266/how-to-create-pdf-file-with-all-your-bookmarks-displayed)

Comment: Sorry I just saw that this was already answered.